# Javascript - event.target.offsetParent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am facing the following situation:

- there is `mousemove` event registered on cells of a table which resides in this hierarchy `BODY -> Something1 -> Something2 -> Something3 -> Table -> Cell`
- I would like to trace the ID of element **Something2** to do something with it further. In my view, the ID can be retrived in one of the following methods:

  - `e.target.offsetParent.offsetParent.offsetParent.id` - which is hardcoded & I don't like it
  - loop through all parents of `e.target` and match the class [Yes, I know the element's class name] of the specific parent whose ID is what I would like to retrieve.

Now, the question is, is there a better way to achieve this? Something like jQuery's find or something?

Example: `e.target.findOnOffsetParents('<.CLASS_NAME>');`

EDITED: Included code involved

`$(document).on("mousemove", 'table', function (e) { 
   Console.log($(e.target).parents('.object').length); //this one results '0' 
   Console.log($(e.target).closest('.object').length); // so does this 
   Console.log($(e.target).parents().find('.object')); //this one picks all elements with class name 'object' regardless of whether or not it is a parent of the e.target 
  });`

Comment: I think you're after `$(e.target).parents(".class")` or `.closest(".class")` - depends on what sort of rules you have and what your markup is really

Comment: @SmokeyPHP, Using parents() or Closest on e.target element seems to traverse only a level up which doesnt get to the parent node I am wanting to.

Comment: Read the docs _For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree._

Comment: @Srii Actually they both go more than one level - try it yourself in the console on this page, `$("#question").closest("body")` and `$("#question").parents("body")` both select the body tag, despite it being multiple levels above the `#question` element. Perhaps you could create a jsFiddle with your markup and JS usage?

Comment: Sure, I am aware of the fact that the parents can traverse more than one level up, in a direct reference. Does this apply to event targets as well? I'll edit my question to add the code I have in place

Comment: @Srii I've set up a jsFiddle to show how they work: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QrLaC/). Open the console and click on the table cell. I wonder if there's a confusion with your markup and how you expect it to work?

Comment: @Srii Regarding your comment about working the same for event targets, yes it's exactly the same because `event.target` is a reference to an element just like `document.getElementById()` or similar would return. Hopefully the fiddle above will help clarify things.

Comment: @SmokeyPHP, thank you for your help. With the help of your fiddle, I had identified a mistake in my reference. Could you post it as an answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you're searching for, and what you're doing with the result(s), you'll want to use either [`.parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) or [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

`$(elem).parents('.object')` - returns all parents of `elem` with a class of `object`

`$(elem).closest('.object')` - returns the first parent of `elem` that has a class of `object`

I would assume you want the latter, which would be:

```
$(e.target).closest('.object')
```

This [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QrLaC/) shows how each works in a set-up similar to what you've mentioned in your question